# Restricting User Access in Debian Squeeze

Tags: security, ssh, debian, sftp, jail

I've been contemplating ways to restrict user access to their own directories, not allowing them to navigate above their own user directory.

I'm using SFTP, and don't want to install regular FTP because of all of the extra security problems that introduces.

`rbash` sounds like a good idea, minus the fact it disables `cd`. I want the user(s) to be able to create directories in their home directory, and navigate through their own folders.

A `chroot` jail sounds like it comes with its own set of problems, and sounds like more of a headache than it's worth.

So, my question is, is there an easier way to limit a user to only being able to navigate their user directory, and not anything above their user directory?

Comment: Why do you think chroot is a headache?  With recent versions of OpenSSH it is borders on being trivially easy in my experience.  Is there some specific issue that you believe you would have with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can limit them to just SFTP and not allowing them to login via ssh, then you can use the chroot facilities built into openssh. [here is a good article explaining how](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/590)

Answer (score 0):

So, following the link and instructions Stew pointed me to, I was able to get this working. I had to make a few changes, though, to get SSH keys to work properly, though, so I thought I'd post a detailed list of what I did, for others to read.

### To `chroot` a User Using SSH for SFTP Only Access:

*As of Debian Squeeze 6.0.5 and OpenSSH 5.5p1*

1. Add a user: `adduser username`
2. Add a group to assign users to that's for users you want to chroot:

   `addgroup sftponly` <-- group name doesn't really matter, as long as
   you change it in all the places below
3. Add user to group: `usermod -G groupname username`
4. Install libpam-chroot: `apt-get install libpam-chroot`
5. Add the following line to `/etc/pam.d/login`

   `session    required   pam_chroot.so debug`
6. Go to: `/usr/share/doc/libpam-chroot/examples`
7. Then: `chmod 744 setup-chrootdir-shell.sh` so you can run the script
8. Run the script, specifying the directory after the script:

   `./setup-chrootdir-shell.sh /path/to/userdir`
9. Verify that the directory that the script just created exists, is
   owned by user and group root, and is set to 755 permissions.
10. Change home directory for user: `usermod -m -d /home/chrootdir/home username`
11. Disable user's shell: `chsh -s /bin/false username`
12. Copy user's files to the new directory (.ssh folder, .profile,
     etc.)
13. Edit the sshd config file: `vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

    `# %h/.ssh/authorized_keys is the default`

    `AuthorizedKeysFile      /home/%u/.ssh/authorized_keys`

    `# Subsystem for chroot jail`

    `# Default is Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server`

    `Subsystem sftp internal-sftp`

    `# Chroot jail config`

    `Match group sftponly`

    `ChrootDirectory /home/chrootdir/home/%u`

    `X11Forwarding no`

    `AllowTcpForwarding no`

    `ForceCommand internal-sftp`

    `Match`
14. If you are using `AllowUsers`, add this user to it.

    `AllowUsers username`
15. Edit `/etc/passwd` and change the user directory location for the
     user

    `vi /etc/passwd`

    e.g: `username:x:1001:1002:/home/chrootdir/home:/bin/false`
16. restart ssh: `/etc/init.d/ssh restart`